# Position two div in one span correctly

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have to set a text and one image just at the bottom of the text.

The text and the image must be centered in a div / span.

The div/span must be aligned at 33% left like:

```
left: 33.33%
```

When I'm trying this code :

```
<span style="display:table;left: 33.33%;">    
<div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:-35px;font-size:12px;">Text</div>
<div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;" class="cursor jauge"></div>
</span>
```

The div elements are not placed into the span and I don't know why!
There are the cursor and jauge classes :

```
.cursor {
    background: url("../img/cursor.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 18px 18px;
}

.jauge {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
}
```

Thanks to help me !

Comment: Except for `<a>` tags in HTML5, it is invalid markup to put a block-level element (`<div>`) inside of an inline element (`<span>`). You should change the `<span>` to a block element (like a `<div>`), or change the `<div>`s to inline elements (like `<span>`s).

Comment: @clement, Your code doesn't include specification of `background-position` of the **background-image**. Besides there is a need of specifying the css style attribute `position` correctly both for the `span` and the inner 'div's. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the `span` as `position:absolute` otherwise it will not take the position you assigned with `left:33.33%` besides giving the inner elements style as `position:relative` then the elements will be placed with positioning relative to their probable position.

So your code should be:

```
<span style="display:table; left:33.33%; position:absolute;">
    <div style="width:100%; position:relative; top:-35px; font-size:30px;">Text</div>
    <div style="width:100%; position:relative; top:-20px; font-size:12px;" class="cursor jauge"></div>
</span>
```

You have to change the css class `cursor` as follows to align the image to center:

```
.cursor {
    background: url("../img/cursor.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: 18px 18px;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is still using the issue of invalid markup (`<div>`s don't go inside of `<span>`s). The behavior of browsers with respect to invalid markup is unknown and likely different between browsers, so there's no guarantee any fix will work on all browsers.

Comment: @ajp15243 At least it worked in 2 browsers I tested, **chrome** and **IE9**. I just tried to keep the OP's code as much unchanged as possible. Hence didn't change the `span` to `div`.

Comment: There's no guarantee that Chrome or IE9 will continue to behave the way you observed in the future with invalid markup. I understand trying to keep changes to a minimum, but it's often better to point out *all* the (potentially or actually) breaking mistakes of someone's code, and provide a fixed version, provided you point out all of the changes you made and why. Also, sometimes removing as much code as possible while still seeing the same issue is best, as it trims away distracting and unnecessary excess.

Comment: ok but I want to center the two elements.. For instance here I have a picture of 20px width and the text is 30px, so I want that the text is centered with the picture @RajeshPaul

Comment: Humm @RajeshPaul : ok thanks but the cursor still in the left :-/

Comment: margin: auto on the div of the cursor solved my problem ! Thanks !!! I will try it on mobile devices now :-)

Answer (score 0):

A span is meant to be an inline element.
Try using a div instead of a span:

```
<div style="display:table;left: 33.33%;">
  <div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:-35px;font-size:12px;">Text</div>
  <div style="display:block;position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;" class="cursor jauge"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thanks @ForOhFor but the left position is not applied to the inner div's, so I can't set them center

Comment: @clement do you want 33% padding? try `padding-left:33.33%` in the outer div then

Comment: @ForOhFor : ok with padding it's ok, but how center the two inner div's ?